# How to validate session and keep HTML in cache storage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, file, .htaccess

I am trying to make web app more efficient, I have a static model, very simple:
I have something like this in escense:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mycssfile.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjsfile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <!-- Some static HTML code here -->
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <!-- Non-static code -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The thing here is that my **content** class changes very often, I do a lot of AJAX requests, everytime I do a request I do it to two different type of files.

- One is a PHP file that is requesting some data from the databse, so after the validations I return the requested data in JSON format
- The other one is an almost-pure HTML file, I say almost cause I use PHP to check if the user has logged in or not, In case they haven't I just return a "You haven't logged in" file.

The problem comes with the fact the PHP files are not storaged in browser cache, and when it comes to slow connections, well there's a problem rigth there. They last, they don't appear "immeadiatly"

I tried to add the most repetitive requests to `<template>` tags, but those are just a few buttons that call the same HTML code, and the site is very big, with a lot of different HTML and JS files.

The question would be: is there any other way to check the session and keep the pure HTML code cached?

In case not, what could be the best directive I could take in this situtation?

Should I remove the PHP code and just leave them without the log-in verification?

I want to state that I do NOT generate HTML code by PHP, as I said, there's two PHP type of files that I use and the problems comes with the second one, let's say those are static HTML files.

Maybe i could do it with htaccess, thats why I add it on the tags, I don't know,

I just need some advise to take the best decision

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider making your HTML files completely static and serving them from a CDN. You can program JavaScript to show a loading state while the PHP files are loaded.

Comment: Also `<template>` tags have nothing to do with the cache

Comment: @kemp I know, I know, I use those tags 'cause I have buttons like "search client", which is a portion of HTML that has tables, inputs (where you input the name to search) and it also includes some JS code and the like. I have that in `<template>` tags cause that "search client" is called several times by several dynamically added HMTL files on the content class, I have them inside those tags cause I just need to use JS to call that code and paste it on a type of "POP-UP Window". But I can't do that to every HTML files I have, just on those buttons that I use on a lot of HTML files...

Comment: If you want to check whether the viewer has permission to view a page first, then just “hard-core”, til-the-cows-come-home caching, probably doesn’t make that much sense to begin with. That I get served content from cache without any further checks, just because someone else used the same browser right before me, even if they logged out properly as they were supposed to, when they were done - that is probably not what you want.

Comment: So you would at least have to check with the server, again, whether I am allowed to see what I requested. The server can then still respond with “yeah, all good, please serve the content you already got from the cache.” That is a bit of a broader topic, I’d recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Conditional_requests as a starting point on this.